# how to detach event listener in directive with host property?

Tags: angular

in the [angular2 document](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html)

it says

> We must detach our listener when the directive is destroyed to avoid memory leaks.

The question is how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We could have attached an event listener to the native element (el.nativeElement) with plain old JavaScript. There are at least three problems with that approach:

This means **if** you would add it using

```
el.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

then you would have to detach it using

```
el.nativElement.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler)
```

But if you use Angulars declarative approach, Angular takes care to detach the event listener.

Comment: duh! I see. I misread it. And webpack hot reload  somehow mess up angular declarative event detach process. Thx !